# Why doesn't the Keras model start training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm making a model to recognize objects in a 700x700 image. I have this model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(700, 700, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1,  activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm trying to train it with 146 images (146x700x700 tensor as x_train and array (146,) as Y_train:

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=2)
```

This is what I see in the output:

```
Epoch 1/5

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

I tried changing `batch_size` and `epochs`, but it didn't help

Comment: Does it train if you use 10 images? Perhaps you're running out of memory.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347252/tensorflow-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xc0000409-status-stack This person is having the same exit code as you

Comment: @Anonymous If I use 10 images the training still doesn't start. I see the same error.

Comment: @Nick ODell thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that PyCharm hides errors when you run code directly from it. I ran the code from the command line and saw an OOM error. I made my model smaller and it worked for me.